# How to tick a CheckBoxColumn when I select a row in a DataGrid in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

My DataGrid lists contacts saved in the database:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ContactsView}"
            Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
            x:Name="contactsDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            EnableRowVirtualization="True" Padding="10"
            CanUserAddRows="False"
            RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected"
            SelectionChanged="contactsDataGrid_SelectionChanged">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Select" Width="50" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Salutation}" Header="Salut." />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding FirstName}" Header="First Name" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding LastName}" Header="Last Name" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding EmailAddress}" Header="Email Address" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Mobile}" Header="Mobile Number" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding BroadDesignation}" Header="Broad Designation" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Designation}" Header="Designation" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

The user should select a row by clicking on it. When a selection is made, the contact is added to another list which is used later:

```
private List<Contact> SelectedContacts = new List<Contact>();
private void contactsDataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    DataGrid ThisGrid = (DataGrid)sender;            
    Contact SelectedContact = (Contact)ThisGrid.SelectedItem;

    if (!SelectedContacts.Contains(SelectedContact))
        SelectedContacts.Add(SelectedContact);
}
```

How can I make it so that when the user makes a selection, the `CheckBoxColumn` changes to a state where the checkbox is checked so that the user knows they've already selected that row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add another Property to your class called `IsSelected`. In the `SelectionChanged` Method you just have to set the property to true and refresh the dataGrid.

Something like the following (not tested):

```
private void contactsDataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    DataGrid ThisGrid = (DataGrid)sender;            
    Contact SelectedContact = (Contact)ThisGrid.SelectedItem;
    SelectedContact.IsSelected = true;
    contactsDataGrid.Items.Refresh();

    if (!SelectedContacts.Contains(SelectedContact))
        SelectedContacts.Add(SelectedContact);
}
```

Comment: Since Contact is my actual data model I don't know if I want to do that, but I can change my bindings to give me my ContactsViewModel and add it on there

Comment: Use a `DataAccessObject` and map from your data model

Comment: I'm having some trouble removing the selection if I click on a row a 2nd time. Any chance you can assist with that as well?

Comment: `SelectedContact.IsSelected = !SelectedContact.IsSelected` should help. With this it is switching the value every time you are clicking on the row